# How to revert a string into a command?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I actually need more than one item from the page but they are all under the same headers and I really don't want to repeat the same `soup_wash.find("td", headers="tf89c8e5b-5207-48e7-a536-1f50ee7f5088c{}").text.strip()` line every time, so I am trying to set `text` as the directory to save time.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def html(url):

    return BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml")

soup_wash = html("https://www.washtenaw.org/3108/Cases")

text = 'soup_wash.find("td", headers="tf89c8e5b-5207-48e7-a536-1f50ee7f5088c{}").text.strip()'

item1 = text.format("2")
item2 = text.format("6")

print(item1, item2) # Supposed to print -> 1561, 107 but it actually prints str(text) formatted.
```

I need bs4 to process the string of item1 and item2 but I'm not sure how to do so.

Comment: Untested but perhaps `finder = lambda n: soup_wash.find("td", headers="tf89c8e5b-5207-48e7-a536-1f50ee7f5088c{}".format(n)).text.strip()` then you can call `finder `later, e.g., `item1 = finder("2")`

Comment: @JustinEzequiel how does lamba work?  btw it works

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html?highlight=lambda#small-functions-and-the-lambda-expression

Answer (score 1):

I personally wouldn't use the value `tf89c8e5b-5207-48e7-a536-1f50ee7f5088c{}` to get `Total Cases` and `Total Deaths` values, because it looks it will change any time.

Instead, grab first table and use standard python indexing to get the columns. For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.washtenaw.org/3108/Cases'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

print('{:<15}{}'.format('Total Cases', 'Total Deaths'))
for tr in soup.select('table')[0].select('tr:has(td)'):
    tds = [td.get_text() for td in tr.select('td')]
    print('{:<15}{}'.format(tds[1], tds[5]))
```

Prints:

```
Total Cases    Total Deaths
1561           107
338            3
1899           110
```